# How to set double color for the TEXT in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I would like to paint my text with two colors. From top to middle and middle to bottom.
Looks like there is no simple way to do this in flutter.

Example, let's say I have letter "B", I want to color blue from top to middle and color black from middle to bottom.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to do this by using `TextPainter` and `CustomPaint`.

If you want the exact drawing you've shared I would recommend using `CustomPaint` and creating the respective shapes you want to draw. However if you want normal text with two colours this approach would work.

```
class BicoloredText extends StatelessWidget {
  const BicoloredText(this.text,
      {required this.style,
      required this.topColor,
      required this.bottomColor,
      this.maxWidth,
      Key? key})
      : super(key: key);
  final String text;
  final TextStyle style;
  final Color topColor;
  final Color bottomColor;
  final double? maxWidth;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final TextPainter textPainter = TextPainter(
      text: TextSpan(
        text: text,
        style: style,
      ),
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
    )..layout(maxWidth: maxWidth ?? double.infinity);

    return Container(
      child: CustomPaint(
        size: textPainter.size,
        painter: BicoloredTextPainter(
          text,
          style: style,
          maxWidth: maxWidth,
          topColor: topColor,
          bottomColor: bottomColor,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BicoloredTextPainter extends CustomPainter {
  const BicoloredTextPainter(this.text,
      {required this.style, required this.topColor, required this.bottomColor, this.maxWidth});

  final String text;
  final TextStyle style;
  final double? maxWidth;
  final Color topColor;
  final Color bottomColor;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {


    final tpTop = TextPainter(
      text: TextSpan(
        text: text,
        style: style.copyWith(color: topColor),
      ),
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr
    )..layout(maxWidth: maxWidth ?? double.infinity);


    final tpBottom = TextPainter(
        text: TextSpan(
          text: text,
          style: style.copyWith(color: bottomColor),
        ),
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr
    )..layout(maxWidth: maxWidth ?? double.infinity);

    
    tpBottom.paint(canvas, Offset.zero);
    canvas.save();
    canvas.clipRect(Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height/2));
    tpTop.paint(canvas, Offset.zero);
    canvas.restore();

  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

`maxWidth` is there in case you want your text to have width constraints.

[image]