# How can I split a text in 2 color vertically in Flutter

Tags: flutter, fonts, gradient

I'm new to Flutter and trying to do something similar to [this](https://jsfiddle.net/5rJ8R/) :

```
div {
  font: 40px Arial;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0d2172 0%,#0d2172 50%,#ff2828 50%,#ff0000 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

but in Flutter.

I've tried with gradient and a shaderMask already, but it's not what I want...

Any ideas?

Thank you very much

Comment: There is already a similar question & answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68328069/how-to-set-double-color-for-the-text-in-flutter

Comment: Question has been already asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I have managed to do with flutter . Propably works for you
[image: ReCreation in flutter]

You first need to add the Gradient

```
final Gradient  _gradient = const LinearGradient(
        begin:  Alignment(0.5, 1),
        end: Alignment(0.5, 0),
        colors: <Color>[
          Color(0xff1f005c),
          Color(0xffffb56b),
          
        ],
        stops : [1,1],
        tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
      );
```

Then you change your text to this :

```
ShaderMask(
      blendMode: BlendMode.modulate,
      shaderCallback: (size) => _gradient.createShader(
        Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height),
      ),
      child: Text(
        'ABCDEFGH',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontSize: 60,
        ),),
      )
```